# Does std::stof parse the whole string or stops at the first whitespace/newline?

Tags: c++

**Edit:**

Went with `atof` instead because it will not produce a copy in such a scenario. From looking at two implementations, it should stop after the first non valid sign.

**Original:**

consider this simple setup:

```
const char* string = "1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0";
float float1 = stof(string);
float float2 = stof(string + 4);
float float3 = stof(string + 8);
```

In such a scenario will stof parse always until the end or stops at the first whitespace after the initial position?

I need to parse a very long float list encoded into a string, so I basically need to know if I have to copy the number into a sperate (small) buffer and call stof on this buffer, or I can use stof as above.

Comment: what happened when you tried?

Comment: *"I need to parse a very long float list"* Make sure in real you don't make a copy of the string on each call like you do in the snippet.

Comment: FWIW you can use string streams to make this a lot easier: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4077ff5f14cb8631

Answer (score 0):

It discards leading whitespaces and parses the whole string. Excerpt from the [std::stof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) reference (emphasis mine):

> Function **discards** any whitespace characters (as determined by
>   std::isspace()) until first non-whitespace character is found. Then it
>   takes **as many** characters **as possible** to form a valid floating-point
>   representation and converts them to a floating-point value.

In your case with `string + 4` and `string + 8` expressions you are supplying the `"2.0 3.0 4.0"` and `"3.0 4.0"` strings to a function. You should also avoid naming your variable `string`.

Comment: This just says that it will discards leading whitespaces?

Comment: @AlexanderWeinrauch it also says "as many characters as possible to form a valid floating-point representation" so eg `0.123as d 1.0 b` will be interpreted as `0.123`

Comment: My question was if stof would stop internally after the first non valid character. So in your example at 'a'.